# How to accelerate the calculation speed for one-line code in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, parallel-processing

I have a very large dataset and want to conduct some statistical analysis. There is only one line code needed for the calculation, but it may take a few days. Is there any way to acceleratethe process?

At first I think parallelization may be a good solution, but then I was told that parallelization for a single call is not possible. Here is an example,

```
set.seed(1234)
mydata=rnorm(5000*150)
mydata=matrix(mydata,ncol=150)

library(parallel)
cl.cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cl.cores)
clusterSetRNGStream(cl,iseed=1234)
clusterExport(cl,"mydata")
clusterEvalQ(cl,library(NbClust))
nc = clusterApply(cl,2,function(min.nc) fun=NbClust(mydata,min.nc=min.nc,max.nc = 8,method = "kmeans"))
stopCluster(cl)
```

For this example, the speed is not increased as the CPU occupation of the desktop remains around 30%, which is the normal value.

Comment: Yes, more suitable for SO.

Comment: You could try optimizing the parallelization. Perhaps load-balancing could help a bit, perhaps you should send chunks of your matrix to the nodes at once. Otherwise, you could consider using compiled code, e.g., implement this in Rcpp. But first you should consider if what you are doing there is sensible. If something takes days to compute one should take some time to reconsider the algorithm.

Comment: @Roland Could you give me an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the source code of `NbClust` and then optimize this function.

For example, you could try moving redundant computations out of this method (to only have to do them once).

If the function is still R code, rewrite it in C++ (i.e. Rcpp). This will greatly speed up the function, as pure R code is very slow.